# Backbone initialize: function( options ) not working in V9

Tags: backbone.js

I just upgrade a site I worked on from  Backbone.js 0.5.3 to  Backbone.js 0.9.2
When I did I get an undefined for my options parameter that I use in my models initialize method. What has changed from V.5 to V.9

initialize: function( options ) {`enter code here`
}

Ok here is my model structure. Everything works fine in 0.5.3 but when I use 0.9.2 options no longer works.

```
this.myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: function() {
            return {
                maxDays: 7,
                index: 0

            };
        },

        initialize: function( options ) {

        }

})



this.model = new myModel();
```

In version 0.5.3 options will show all the attributes that were set in the defaults object.
but in version 0.9.2 this no longer works it returns undefined.
I can not post a link because of the client sensitivity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The signature of initialize remains unchanged I believe from 0.5 to 0.9. However, you only get options passed in if you pass them to the constructor. Check out the [annotated source for Backbone.Model](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html). Whenever you instantiate a new model instance, the constructor does this:

```
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

So whatever you pass to the constructor gets passed unmodified to initialize. So look in your code for cases where you are instantiating a new model instance but not passing 2 arguments (attributes and options).

Based on your code sample, you now need to define `initialize` as taking 2 parameters: `attributes` and `options` and when creating your models, if you want to just pass options do:

```
var model = new Model(null, options);
```

or

```
var model = new Model({}, options);
```

I think the specific change that broke your code is the switch from calling initialize with explicit arguments in 0.5.3 to using apply and arguments in 0.9.3 like this:

```
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

So in 0.9 you can get access to your defaults through `this.attributes`, but they won't come in as a function parameter unless they came in as a parameter to the constructor function.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {x: 42, y: 43},
    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
        console.log(arguments, attributes, this.attributes);}
});
var m = new MyModel();
```

That will log `[], undefined, Object` since arguments is empty, attributes is undefined since nothing was passed to the constructor, but the defaults HAVE been set in `this.attributes` and are there for you to use.

Comment: I added more code above. So initialize should have 2 parameters. Options been the second. But if you say that hasn't changed since V5 then that doesn't explain why it works with just one parameter in V5 and not in V9

Comment: I checked the 0.5.3 source code: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/29b60e53fa18b6fffb4a21d0d1c8c9fdbde43b6c/backbone.js#L132 and the 0.9.2 source code: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/863814e519e630806096aa3ddeef520afbb263ff/backbone.js#L189 and both take attributes then options. Looking at your code now...

Comment: Ok thanks, so I added a second parameter to my code and still it returns undefined for both parameters in V9. initialize: function( attributes, options ) { IS this what you are referring to? Then in V5 only the first parameter works in my setup.

Comment: We're talking about arguments. You need to post a snippet of the code that passes them, where you create your model, as well as the model code in order for me to intelligently help you. You have only posted 1/2 of the relevant code so far.

Comment: Ok your example above is how I'm calling my model. The on;y difference is I don't pass it anything. var model = new Model(); In V5 options returns all the attributes in defaults object. In V9 it returns undefined.

Comment: By defaults object I mean defaults: function() {}

Comment: I just posted all my code that worked in V 0.5.3 but the options no longer works in V0.9.2 not sure what else I can post you as you say I only have posted half the code.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I see what you are getting at. You pass no args to the constructor, you get no args in initialize. This is due to the use of apply/arguments in 0.9. HOWEVER, the defaults should be there in `this.attributes`. I'll add a code snippet I just tested to my answer.

Comment: OK, see most recent code snippet. I _think_ that will get you going.